# AWS API action to list EC2 Instance associated with a specific Elastic Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have looked through the AWS EC2 and ELB apis and I cannot figure out a way that I can list the EC2 Instances that are associated with an Elastic Load Balancer. I would think that there is a way to do this, since it is so easy to do on the console. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed possible via the [Elastic Load Balancing](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) API as expected:

The [DescribeLoadBalancers](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeLoadBalancers.html) action returns a list of *LoadBalancerDescriptions*, where each [LoadBalancerDescription](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/APIReference/API_LoadBalancerDescription.html) contains an *Instances* element in turn, which provides the desired *list of EC2 instance IDs for the LoadBalancer*.

Comment: Thanks, I realize this information was not showing on the CLI until I used the --show-long or --show-xml flag